# Duda sobre INADDR_ANY

Tags: c++, c, socket

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que deseo comunicar un ordenador con una Raspberry Pi mediante el protocolo de comunicación UDP. Mi duda viene a la hora de declarar la dirección IP. He leído en algunas páginas que esto vale para concectarse a todas las interfaces locales. Mi duda es sobre el la amplitud del término local, ¿al estar trabajando con dos ordenadores distintos, puedo utilizar el INADDR_ANY, o estos se les considera fuera del ámbito local y voy a tener que declarar las direcciones IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creas un socket en el lado servidor, tienes que asignarle una IP y un puerto para que los clientes puedan especificar a dónde conectarse o a dónde enviar el datagrama UDP.

Si conoces la IP de tu servidor, puedes especificar esa IP como parte de los parámetros que pasas al `bind()`, pero ello implicará dos cosas:

1. Si tu servidor tenía varias interfaces de red, cada una con su IP, al especificar una IP en concreto sólo recibirá datos que provengan de esa interfaz.
2. Si tu servidor cambia la IP, deberías cambiar también el programa, o dejará de funcionar.

Por ambas razones no es habitual especificar una IP concreta en el código, y resulta más conveniente usar la constante `INADDR_ANY`, que en realidad es la IP especial `0.0.0.0` que representa "cualesquiera que sean las IPs de todos los interfaces de red de este ordenador".

Al usar `INADDR_ANY` por tanto consigues dos cosas:

1. Admitirás datos que provengan de cualquiera de los interfaces de red que tu servidor tenga.
2. Aunque el servidor cambie su IP, el programa seguirá funcionando sin cambios.

La mayoría de los ordenadores, a menos que sean routers, tendrán sólo una tarjeta de red, pero como mínimo dos interfaces de red (puede tener más, virtuales). Puedes ver los que tienes con el comando `ifconfig`. Como mínimo verás dos: uno con la IP que haya sido asignada a la tarjeta de red, y otro con la IP especial `127.0.0.1`, que representa a la interfaz "local" de *loopback* (llamada en linux `lo`). Esta es una interfaz de red especial que no recibe peticiones de "fuera" sino sólo de dentro de la máquina. Resulta muy útil cuando el cliente y el servidor están en el mismo ordenador.

El uso habitual de `bind()` es asignarle una de estas dos IPs:

- `0.0.0.0` (`INADDR_ANY`) para que admita conexiones de la tarjeta de red, sin necesidad de tener que conocer qué IP es. Además recibirá conexiones de la interfaz *loopback* (y del resto de interfaces de red, físicas o virtuales, que pudiera tener).
- `127.0.0.1` para que admita conexiones sólo de la interfaz *loopback*, lo que impedirá que nadie pueda acceder al servidor, sino es ejecutando el cliente en la propia máquina. Esto puede parecer un poco inútil, pero tiene sentido si usas túneles SSH pues en ese caso quien recibe los datos es un proceso local que después se conecta con el servidor a través del *loopback*.

Ten en cuenta no obstante que todo esto tiene que ver con las IPs de las interfaces de red que tenga el servidor. Esas IPs podrían ser IPs públicas (con lo que podrías conectar a ellas desde cualquier ordenador del mundo), o más probablemente IPs locales (tipo `192.168.0.1`, etc.) que sólo son accesibles a ordenadores en la red local. Típicamente en este caso habrá un router haciendo NAT, y ese router sí tendrá una IP pública. Configurando apropiadamente el router con reenvío de puertos puedes hacer que el servidor pueda ser accedido "desde fuera", pero eso no tiene nada qué ver con `bind()` ni con `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: quedé con una uda, si bind() es para agregar el 0.0.0.0 o el localhost, entonces la ip  publica que quiero agregar para recibir desde fuera de la red entonces no trabaja con bind() ?

Comment: @emiliortega También piedes usar `bind()` para poner una IP concreta, de una de tus interfaces de red (p.ej., la IP pública). Pero si haces eso solo podrá recibir conexiones desde esa interfaz, y no desde la 127.0.0.1. Ademas si al reiniciar la IP publica cambiara, tendrás que modificar el código para que figure la nueva IP. Por eso suele usarse mas la 0.0.0.0 que admite también conexiones desde fuera y no depende de cambios de IP.

Comment: gracias por responder, pero una ultima duda, si yo entonces ejecuto el cliente asi  ./cliente 192.168.92.128 3600 y el server lo ejecuto ./server 3600, y si lo configuro con INADDR_ANY en servidor, quiere decir que si funcionaria porque INADDR_ANY estaría asignando 0.0.0.0 ?  (todo esto es ejecutando en la misma maquina tanto cliente y server) sorry pero tengo un poco de confusion con esto de los sockets

Comment: @EmiliOrtega Sí, así es. INADDR_ANY y 0.0.0.0 son lo mismo. Y es una IP "comodin" que representa "todas mis interfaces de red"

Comment: y en el caso de que ya no trabajara en localhost, el INADDR_ANY ya no tendria nada que ver en eso verdad? sigue siendo INADDR_ANY solo que deberia hacer un port forwarding para que la ip que pongo en el cliente (la publica de mi server) pueda llegar al servidor (la privada).
Otra duda que tengo es por qué el cliente no usa el bind() ? como luego le server le puede mandar un mensaje al cliente sin saber la ip de este?

Comment: efectivamente, si rediriges puertos en un router, el servidor seguirá recibiendo las peticiones oor la misma IP (desde el router) y sigue funcionando INADDR_ANY. El cliente no necesita bind() porque por defecto ya hace uno a la IP 0.0.0.0 y puerto 0. El puerto 0 indica que deja que el operativo elija para el un puerto al azar. En el servidor no quieres esto porque necesitas que el puerto sea uno concreto para que el cliente pueda conectar con el, pero en el cliente no importa porque nadie conectara. El servidor averigua la IP y puerto de un cliente a aceptar la conexión.

Comment: Pero tu programa no necesita siquiera conocer la IP y puerto del cliente, porque usando TCP el servidor crea en el `accept()` un socket de datos que ya esta conectado con el del cliente. Todo lo que el servidor escriba en ese socket llegará al cliente, sin necesidad de especificar IP ni puerto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora me queda todo muchisimo mas claro!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108105/discussion-between-emiliortega-and-abulafia).